# Problem with AD user authentication after joining Windows Domain

Tags: samba, active-directory, kerberos

I've been trying to add my linux machine into the AD of my office in order to work without problems. I started following this guide: [SSSD and Active Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html) in my ubuntu 16.04 (fresh install) and got stuck trying to start the sssd.service because sssd needed the kerberos keytab that didn't exist on the system.

Anyway, after days of search on Google I found the way to join the windows domain. I can check the status with "sudo net ads info" and get the expected result:

> LDAP server: 10.1.1.3
>   LDAP server name: DC.DOMAIN.local
>   Realm: DOMAIN.LOCAL
>   Bind Path: dc=DOMAIN,dc=LOCAL
>   LDAP port: 389
>   Server time: mié, 01 jun 2016 12:31:36 VET
>   KDC server: 10.1.1.3
>   Server time offset: 0

The commands "wbinfo -u" and "wbinfo -g" show the complete list of Domain users and groups. The commands "wbinfo -i DOMAIN\\username" works well. This is the output of the command with my domain username:

> DOMAIN\japonte:*:4294967295:4294967295:Jose Aponte:/home/DOMAIN/japonte:/bin/false

However, when I try "getent passwd" or "getent group" it shows only the local users and group: First it shows the local users, then there it waits for 2 or 3 seconds and then finish, like if the system were trying to search in the AD or something. If I try "getent passwd DOMAIN\\username" I get the same output as before:

> DOMAIN\japonte:*:4294967295:4294967295:Jose Aponte:/home/DOMAIN/japonte:/bin/false

I don't know what I'm missing because I try to authenticate at the login screen and the terminal using "su - " without success.

Also, Here is the content of the configuration files of Kerberos, Samba, SSSD and nsswitch:

[Samba, Kerberos, SSSD and Nsswitch Configuration Files](http://pastebin.com/pw9eHLhQ)

I took the time to replace the domain and machine hostname to "DOMAIN" and "MY-MACHINE". I also had to put all the configuration files in one pastebin because I don't have enough reputation to add more links.

Samba Version: 4.3.9

Thank you in advance,
Best Regards

**Edit:**

Just from a few hours without making any modification to the files, I tried to run "su - DOMAIN\\username" and it asked me for the password but, after some 20 or 30 seconds it shows me the error message "No passwd entry for user for DOMAIN\\username". When using the command with a false domain username it gives me the "not found" error. Just another clue in order to get this problem solved.

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue with the same guide. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hello @davidpricedev I couldn't solve it. I had to use Centrify on Ubuntu as a workaround